# Rails Simple navigation gem how to link to unless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my navigation config file I have:

```
sub_nav.item t.id, t.h1.force_encoding("UTF-8"), tag_path(d.slug, t.slug, params.except(:controller, :action).merge(:tag_id => t.id, :page => nil, :kat_id => nil))
```

I don't want it to be a link `if params[:tag_id] = t.id`

Comment: here is the full config file http://pastie.org/private/dvv9x8jpmelmekxdw39aoa where you can see the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if params[:tag_id] == t.id
  sub_nav.item t.id, t.h1.force_encoding("UTF-8"), tag_path(d.slug, t.slug, params.except(:controller, :action).merge(:tag_id => t.id, :page => nil, :kat_id => nil))
else
  sub_nav.item t.id, t.h1.force_encoding("UTF-8")
end
```

Comment: I have tried this it throws a wrong number of arguments (2 for 3)